# Describing the elements of: $A=\{x\in \mathbb R\mid (\exists n\in \mathbb N (x=n^2))\to(x>2)\}\setminus\{x\in \mathbb R\mid |x|>1\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Describe the elements of: $A=\{x\in \mathbb R\mid (\exists n\in \mathbb N (x=n^2))\to(x>2)\}\setminus\{x\in \mathbb R\mid |x|>1\}$

I'm not sure I'm allowed to answer this verbally or if there's another way to do this but I'll write my attempt anyway:

I'll check each part separately:

$\{x\in \mathbb R\mid (\exists n\in \mathbb N (x=n^2))\}$ is the set of all reals with a natural square root, so:

$\{x\in \mathbb R\mid (\exists n\in \mathbb N (x=n^2))\to(x>2)\}$ is the set of all reals with a natural square root that are bigger than 2.

$\{x\in \mathbb R\mid |x|>1\}$ is the set of all reals larger than 1 and smaller than -1.

So $A$ is the set of all reals with a natural root, larger than 2 but without any number that is bigger than 1, so the set's difference takes out all the elements from $A$, therefore: $A=\emptyset$ and there are no elements in $A$.

Did I get it right? is there another, more rigorous way to *describe* elements of a set?

Comment: "(...) is the set of all reals with a natural square root that are bigger than $2$". This part is wrong, notice that for instance $\sqrt 2$ is in this set.

Comment: @GitGud so how do you treat the $\to (x>2)$ part? since $\sqrt 2 < 2$

Comment: I'd get rid of $\to$ in favor of a disjunction, as it was done in the answer below. Also note that the first set you consider can more succinctly be described as the set of perfect squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $(\exists n \in \mathbb{N} (x=n^2)) \rightarrow (x >2)$ is equivalent on saying
$$(\forall n \in \mathbb{N} (x\neq n^2)) \mbox{ or } (x > 2)$$
so your set is (I suppose that $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1, 2, 3 \dots\}$)
$$
\begin{align}
A &= \left(( \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ n^2 | n \in \mathbb{N} \} ) \cup (2, + \infty)\right) \cap [-1,1]\\
&= \left( \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ n^2 | n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cap [-1,1] \right) \cup \left((2, + \infty)\cap [-1,1]\right)\\ 
&=[-1,1) \cup \emptyset\\
&= [-1,1)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It's so simple huh... is it possible to do this without using the equivalence: $p\to q \equiv \neg p \vee q$?

Comment: I don't think so, this is in some sense the definition of $\rightarrow$, so it would be strange not to use that equivalence.