# Describing: $\{x\in \mathbb R\mid\forall y\left [(y\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\})\to (y>x) \right ] \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, notation, predicate-logic

> Describe: $\{x\in \mathbb R\mid\forall y\left [(y\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\})\to (y>x) \right ]  \}$ with $x$ as the only parameter.

The inner part can be rewritten: $(y\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\}\to (y>x) \equiv \neg(y\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\})\vee (y>x)\overset{?}{\equiv}(y\not\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t\le3\})\vee (y>x)$

I've placed a question mark because it doesn't make sense, now $y$ is undefined for $(y>x)$. Not negating the $y\in$ leaves me with the same problem: $(y\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t\le3\})\vee (y>x)$ and it's probably wrong.

Maybe De Morgan could help: $(y\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\})\wedge (y\le x)$ now I'm allowed to distribute $\forall$ so we get (not sure if it helps though):
$$\{x\in \mathbb R\mid\forall y(y\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\})\wedge \forall y(y\le x) \}$$

I don't know how to continue from here, could be $\{x\in \mathbb R|x\ge 4\}$?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

EDIT: I think I made a mistake with De Morgan, it should be:

$$\{x\in \mathbb R\mid\exists y\left [(y\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\})\wedge (y\le x)\right ] \} \overset {take: y=4}\equiv \{x\in \mathbb R|x\ge 4\}$$

Comment: I don't feel like addressing what you did. Note, however, that the predicate (dependent on $x$) $\forall y\left [(y\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\})\to (y>x) \right ]$ is saying that all natural numbers greater than $3$ are larger than $x$. This formulation should give you the answer easily. Then you should prove that the resulting set and the given one are equal by proving a double inclusion or whatever.

Comment: @GitGud so I'm totally wrong again... And it should be $\{x∈R|x<3\}$. Shouldn't I be able to reach to it with equivalences like here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1131710/146115 ?

Comment: It should be $\{x\in \mathbb R\colon x<4\}$. Shouldn't you able to get it? Not necessarily, I don't think it's always possible. It would depend on what rules you have.

Comment: A double inclusion in this case would go like this: Take $a\in\{x∈\mathbb R:x<4\}$ since $a<4$ then it's smaller than any natural larger than 3 so $a$ is in the other set. The other side is exactly the same no? @GitGud

Comment: I'd be a bit more formal, but what you did is fine. I'd do it like this. Let $a\in\{x∈\mathbb R:x<4\}$. You wish to prove that $\forall y\left [(y\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\})\to (y>a) \right ]$. It's a universal statement, to prove it start by taking arbitrary $b$. Now you want to prove that $b\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\}\to (b>a)$. It's a conditional statement, to prove it assume the antecedent, that is, suppose $b\in \{t\in \mathbb N\mid t>3\}$ is true. Now you want to prove that $b>a$. Recall that $a<4$. Also $b\in \mathbb N$ and $b>3$, so $b\ge 4$. Therefore $a<4\leq b$.

Comment: If you want to post an answer proving both inclusions by your own words, I'll check it out.

Comment: @GitGud yes thank you, I'll do it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the main set as
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \forall y \in \{4,5,\ldots\} \quad y>x \}.$$
Then, it is clear that the main set is equal to
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x < 4\}.$$

Comment: Writing $...$ isn't considered rigorous as far as I know.